# Using Application.Selection and Application.InputBox to Multiply Two Columns

Tags: arrays, function, excel, vba

Very new to VBA, wanting to learn more. I'm trying something that I could easily do using formulas in a spreadsheet, but I want to learn how to code it.

I basically want to tell the user to select two cell ranges of the same length and multiply them together to return a value. For the purposes of what I would use it for, I'm calculating market values of stocks given the market price and number of shares.

I've the set up, but I don't know what I do to multiply together or return the value

Sub CalculateMV()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range

Set Rng = Application.Selection
Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Select All Market Values", "MV Calculator", Type:=8)

Dim rng3 As Range

Set rng3 = Application.Selection
Set rng3 = Application.InputBox("Select All Market Values", "MV Calculator", Type:=8)

For Each Rng2 In Rng

Is there something large (fundamentally) that I'm missing, like an array or I need to write a function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should mention that I'm trying to return a value for each cell*cell multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since your ranges need to be the same size, you'll need to implement a check to ask the user to "try again" if the ranges don't equal each other, or if one of the ranges is more than 1 column wide.

You will then need to use a `For` loop to multiply each cell. Here's the code I came up with. Currently it only returns the values to the debug/immediate window (press Ctrl+G in VBA to view it), since I don't know where you want the values to actually go, but this should get you started.

```
Sub CalculateMV()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
    Dim RowCount As Long, i As Long
    Dim Result As Double

Lbl_TryAgain1:
    Set Rng1 = Application.InputBox("Select All Market Values, 1st Range", "MV Calculator", Type:=8)
    If Rng1.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Each range must have a maximum of one column. Please try again.", vbExclamation
        Set Rng1 = Nothing
        GoTo Lbl_TryAgain1
    End If
Lbl_TryAgain2:
    Set Rng2 = Application.InputBox("Select All Market Values, 2nd Range", "MV Calculator", Type:=8)
    If Rng2.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Each range must have a maximum of one column. Please try again.", vbExclamation
        Set Rng2 = Nothing
        GoTo Lbl_TryAgain2
    ElseIf Rng1.Rows.Count <> Rng2.Rows.Count Then
        MsgBox "Each range must have the same number of rows. Please try again.", vbExclamation
        Set Rng2 = Nothing
        GoTo Lbl_TryAgain2
    End If

    RowCount = Rng1.Rows.Count

    For i = 1 To RowCount
        Result = Val(Rng1.Cells(i, 1)) * Val(Rng2.Cells(i, 1))
        Debug.Print Result
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Apologies for the beginner questions, but what exactly does "On Error Resume Next" mean?

Comment: It's a type of error handling. See here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm